# How to scale a nodejs app

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, sails.js, scalability

In order to predict our *exploitation costs*, my new associates and I would like to predict our **hosting needs**.

Our application would be a **public** one, involving **increasing number of users**.

We found that, for node.js applications, we basically have 2 options :

- As a service, like *Heroku*
- Take a raw server, dedicated or virtual, like *OVH* here in France

#### Specifications :

The server would be essentially a **backend** one, serving ressources "REST-like" over [socket.io](http://socket.io/) (with *sails.js*' implementation [sails.io.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js))

The usage would basically be, for each user :

- Making a search : server taking a "**request**" (socket event), processing a reasonnable **calculation** (involing a few maths), returning a reasonnable number (< 1000) of "**responses**" (socket event), taken from a database, as json
- the user would make, say, **3 requests** in a raw usage)
- Each user would use the application **twice a day**
- In the background, each user would **send it's location** to the server, still with "REST-like" over socket, say, **every minute**

---

#### Question

*I'd just like to know, what basically would be the process to guess the kind of server we have to purchase ? We would like to "scale as we grow" the server, but we still have to make plans, and I can't realy figure out how to predict the need for 10000 users for example.*

*Would this be about calculating a "per user" server performance unit (Ram, Cpu, "Dyno") and network unit (bandwidth) ?*

Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 0):

It's 7 months ago, but as an answer try to use Google Compute Engine, and use the auto scale function to scale use as you go.  Node.js works on it and you can install any other packages you need.

Load balancing is handled for you by google as well. You pay extras, but you save a lot of time from research/developing scaling issues.

Comment: Hey. Actually the concern here is to estimateur scale costs. I do know elastic cloud solutions such as Heroku, AWS or google one, but I'd like to estimate costs on them.